# How to flush gstreamer pipeline

Tags: flush, seek, gstreamer-0.10

**Case**
Reading from a file continuously and feeding to appsrc element. 
Source - appsrc

I have a GStreamer pipeline in PLAYING state. Now would want the pipeline to flush / clean when I press a button that means appsrc queue should be cleared. The playback should start from whatever buffers are now added to / or were added after flush.

**Issue**
the APIs I used returned false. I am not able to flush.

```
fprintf(stderr, "The flush event start was <%d>",gst_element_send_event(GST_ELEMENT (pipe), gst_event_new_flush_start());    
fprintf(stderr, "The flush event stop was  <%d>",gst_element_send_event(GST_ELEMENT (pipe), gst_event_new_flush_stop()));
```

Both the above returned 0. That means false. 
What is the reason for this false ?

How can I try flushing the data in a pipeline with some API? Or Is there any other API for skipping playback ?

**Tried**

- Sending `gst_event_new_flush_start ()`  and `gst_event_new_flush_stop ()` to the pipeline with and without a gap of some milliseconds
- `gst_event_new_seek (1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0);`
- setting pipeline to NULL and then to PLAYING again

All these could not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not working for me, because I was using **0.10** v of gstreamer.If there is not a constraint to use 0.10 version of `gstreamer`, please use **1.2** version of gstreamer.

However, in v 0.10 the flushing seek generally works as a substitute to flush the pipeline.

While using 1.2v, the two APIs  `gst_event_new_flush_start ()` and `gst_event_new_flush_stop ()` work. In that case you can use the flush directly.

In either way you should be able to flush. Make an internal API where you do a flushing seek and use it as your flush API.

There is a post in [gstreamer-devel mailing list](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/lists/)which has talked about behavior of [flush](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Flushing-a-pipeline-with-appsrc-td4661878.html) in the two versions.